# BroadcastReceiver not always receives

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I have a class that extends `IntentService`; in this class I send an `Intent` that should be received by a `BroadcastReceiver` registered inside an `Activity`.
The problem is that 90% of times the `BroadcastReceiver` receives correctly the `Intent`. 10% it doesn't.
Debugging my app I saw that all my code works perfectly until the `Intent` is sent; the problem occurred after the `Intent` is sent!

This is my code.
Manifest file:

```
...
<receiver
    android:name=".BroadcastReceiver.MediaBroadcastReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true" />
...
```

BroadcastReceiver inside the Activity:

```
public class ContactDetail extends AppCompatActivity implements MediaBroadcastReceiverInterface{
...
   @Override
   public void MediaBroadcastReceiverCallback() {
      //This is the method that is not always called
   }
...
}
```

this is the BrodcastReceiver:

```
public class MediaBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public interface MediaBroadcastReceiverInterface{
       void MediaBroadcastReceiverCallback();      
    }

    private MediaBroadcastReceiverInterface mediaBroadcastReceiverInterface;    
    public static final String PROCESS_RESPONSE = "com.xxx.appname.BroadcastReceiver.MediaBroadcastReceiver.PROCESS_RESPONSE";

    public MediaBroadcastReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){            
        try {
            mediaBroadcastReceiverInterface = (MediaBroadcastReceiverInterface)context;   
            mediaBroadcastReceiverInterface.MediaBroadcastReceiverCallback();
        }
        catch (ClassCastException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Activity doesn't implement the MediaBroadcastReceiverInterface interface");
        }

    }
}
```

This is the IntentService in which I sent the Intent to the BroadCastReceiver

```
public class MediaIntentService extends IntentService {   
    public void send(){            
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction(MediaBroadcastReceiver.PROCESS_RESPONSE);
        broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);        
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);        
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: `received by a BroadcastReceiver registered inside an Activity` Are you sure the Broadcastreceiver is registered when the Intent is fired? In which lifecycle methods do you (un-)register the Broadcastreceiver?

Answer (score 0):

You are statically registering broadcast in manifest.Use below code in manifest. Although in your case i suggest you should register/unregister it at runtime .

```
 <receiver
        android:name=".BroadcastReceiver.MediaBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
    <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. What you mean with "You are statically registering..."?

Comment: statically register -> Registering BroadcastReceiver in Manifest . Its a good practice to register/unregister BroadcastReceiver at runtime only(If not Mandatory).

Comment: I edited my app and registered/unregistered dinamically the BroadcastReceiver inside onCreate()/onDestroy() methods but the problem persist :(

Answer (score 0):

Change your broadcast receiver to

```
public class MediaBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public interface MediaBroadcastReceiverInterface{
       void MediaBroadcastReceiverCallback();      
    }

    private MediaBroadcastReceiverInterface mediaBroadcastReceiverInterface;    
    public static final String PROCESS_RESPONSE = "com.xxx.appname.BroadcastReceiver.MediaBroadcastReceiver.PROCESS_RESPONSE";

    public MediaBroadcastReceiver(MediaBroadcastReceiverInterface media) {
        mediaBroadcastReceiverInterface = media;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){            
        try {
            mediaBroadcastReceiverInterface.MediaBroadcastReceiverCallback();
        }
        catch (ClassCastException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Activity doesn't implement the MediaBroadcastReceiverInterface interface");
        }

    }
}
```

Then remove `receiver` from `manifest` and register it in `Activity` as in

```
public class ContactDetail extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
             @Override
              public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
               ...
                 registerReceiver(new MediaBroadcastReceiver(new MediaBroadcastReceiverInterface(){
                    @Override
                    public void MediaBroadcastReceiverCallback() {
                      //Will be triggered
                    }
                 },new IntentFilter("actionname");
                 ...
               }
     ...
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. You think the problem i cause by the manifest file?

Comment: I hope so, you are using context for triggering the method, which is sent by onreceive method, instead you can use dedicated call back as above